# What is the correct way to use the modulus (%) operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, modulo

In JavaScript the % operator seems to behave in a very weird manner. I tried the following:

```
>>> (0 - 11) % 12
-11
```

Why does it return -11 instead of 1 (as in Python)?

I am sure I am doing or expecting something wrong, but the docs don't tell me what.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fmod from the math module behaves correctly in python:

```
>>> from math import *
>>> fmod(-11, 12)
-11.0
```

-11 is the correct answer..

Comment: "Correct" depends on how you define modulus though. I suspect the JavaScript implementation is correct by their definition too. Follow the link in my answer - the issue isn't as clear as you might expect.

Answer (score 7):

It's behaving correctly according to the way the language is specified (e.g. [ECMA 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)), where it's called the remainder operator rather than the modulus operator. From the spec:

> The result of an ECMAScript floating-point remainder operation is determined by the rules of IEEE arithmetic:
>
> - If either operand is NaN, the result is NaN.
> - The sign of the result equals the sign of the dividend.
> - If the dividend is an infinity, or the divisor is a zero, or both, the result is NaN.
> - If the dividend is finite and the divisor is an infinity, the result equals the dividend.
> - If the dividend is a zero and the divisor is nonzero and finite, the result is the same as the 
>     dividend.
> - In the remaining cases, where neither an infinity, nor a zero, nor NaN is involved, the 
>     floating-point remainder `r` from a dividend `n` and a divisor `d` is defined by the mathematical 
>     relation `r = n - (d * q)` where `q` is an integer that is negative only if `n/d` is negative and 
>     positive only if `n/d` is positive, and whose magnitude is as large as possible without 
>     exceeding the magnitude of the true mathematical quotient of `n` and `d`. `r` is computed and 
>     rounded to the nearest representable value using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode.

In your case `n/d` is negative, so the result is negative.

See the [Wikipedia entry on modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) for more details, including a list of languages with the behaviour in terms of the sign of the result.

Answer (score 1):

There are two similar operations: modulo and remainder. Modulo represents a more mathematical usage, and remainder more IT usage.

Assume we have two integers, a and b.

MOD(a, b) will return a result which has the same sign as b.

REM(a, b) will return a result which has the same sign as a.
 - this is what is implemented in C/C++/C# as the % operator and often confusingly called "mod"

You can think of it like this too:

MOD(a, b) will find the largest integer multiple of b (call it "c") that is smaller than a, and return (a - c).

e.g. MOD(-340,60) we find c = -360 is the largest multiple of 60 that is smaller than -340. So we do (-340 - (-360)) = 20.

REM(a, b) will return a value such that (DIV(a,b) * b) + REM(a, b) = a, where DIV() represents integer division.

So for r = REM(-340, 60)

-340  = DIV(-340,60) * 60 + r 
      = -5 * 60 + r 
      = r - 300

This solves to give us r = -40.

Answer (score 0):

-11 < 12, so i 'suppose' they don't actually divide:
So -11 = 0x12 -11

Have a try with (0-13) % 12

Answer (score 0):

You say MOD(a,b) will return a result with the same sign as b, but then say that it returns (a-c) where c is smaller than a.  This second definition means that it always returns a positive number.  Which is it?